# how to manipulate variables in a factor of a data frame

Tags: r

I need to do some manipulations in  a factor inside my data frame with name phone number.
 the variables must be numeric with lenght 5 
also not contains special char 
and I want to change the format AO-11111, VQ-11111from to  111111 it means erase the first chars and finally transform the rest of variables to na

My data.frame is derived from a .csv file.initial phone_number is a factor data such that
phone_number
VQ-40773
VQ-43685
VQ-44986
40270
41694
42623
.
.

Answer (score 0):

strsplit function will help you to get the value out string.

```
 str="VQ-40773"
(strsplit(str,"-"))[[1]][2] //will return 40773
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove anything the precedes a dash, then:

```
 sub("^([^-]+[-])(.+)", "\\2", phone_number)

> phone_number <- scan(what="")
1:     VQ-40773
2:     VQ-43685
3:     VQ-44986
4:     40270
5:     41694
6:     42623
7: 
Read 6 items
> sub("^([^-]+[-])(.+)", "\\2", phone_number)
[1] "40773" "43685" "44986" "40270" "41694" "42623"
> as.numeric(sub("^([^-]+[-])(.+)", "\\2", phone_number))
[1] 40773 43685 44986 40270 41694 42623
```

The `nchar` function would allow checking the lengths of a character vector. Post an adequate example and, please, do make a greater effort to get punctuation and capitalization correct.

Comment: this code didn't work with variables such us DER04 - 44432 or DER4 in phone_number cause the factor contains 1944 obs and at the result i must get all variable with numeric 5 lenght without special chars and  AO-11111, VQ-11111from to 111111 and NA for the rest

Comment: Post a test dataset with sufficient complexity to illustrate the problems to be solved.

Comment: Factor w/ 1438 levels "",".","25220",..: 871 1 1 847 1 960 458 458 594 1068 ...    41479
VQ-43980
DER8
NA
40928
VQ-44050
DER06-NNA
DER06


38974
VQ-38974
VQ-38974
43398
DER11

Comment: I do not think you have yet posted anything that would not be handled to your specifications by my code. All of the items in `c("41479" ,    "VQ-43980",  "DER8" , NA  , "40928" ,    "VQ-44050" ,
 "DER06-NNA", "DER06" , "38974",  "VQ-38974",  "VQ-38974",  "43398",  "DER11")` have 0 or 5 digit numeric content after the dash. I did tell you that you could have tested to 5 digits with `nchar`, but so far it has not been necessary. The shorter numbers in that output from str)() are not strings but are rather the index-integers of a factor variable.